# Label not updated in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a problem in WPF, that a label is not updated when a method is in progress.
Here is the code.

```
private async void BtnMatching_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (dynamic)ListViewQueries.SelectedItems[0];

    var myQuery = _queryFolder[selectedItem] as Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryDefinition;

    DataTable dtRevision= new DataTable();
    DataTable dtExportData = new DataTable();

    var TTSList = Task<List<UsersModel>>.Factory.StartNew(() => TTSProcessing(TTSFileName));

    LblMessage.Content = "Processing TTS File...";
  //  LblMessage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => LblMessage.Content = "Processing TTS File..."));

        await TTSList;

    if (TTSList.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
    {
     LblMessage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => LblMessage.Content = "File Completed, Now Executing Query...")); //--> This code is not working here
    }

//Other code
}
```

I want to update the LblMessage label when TTSList task is completed. Remember (other code means there is many other code after IF block). 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to set a breakpoint on `BeginInvoke`? Is it `RanToCompletion` or perhaps something else (and therefore no label update)? Btw use `InvokeAsync`.

Comment: @Sinatr: Yes I put two breakpoints; one on RanToCompletion and another on under Action. first It hit on  RanToCompletion when TTSList is completed but another hit on (Action) goes when other code is completed.

Comment: Do you really need the last BeginInvoke ? You are already on the GUI thread ?

Comment: Please provide  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your issue.

Comment: @EmmanuelDURIN: GUI Thread not updating the label. that's y i m using BeginInvoke

Comment: This code doesn't require Dispatcher to update GUI - at least at that place

Comment: can you post your xaml ??

Comment: Is there any solution?????